# Submit oozie jobs from eclipse from different user?

Tags: hadoop, oozie

Whenever is submit jobs from eclipse i see my job submitted under the user name ibm_skalyan however on submitting jobs from Terminal i see the user as biadmin and my job successfully runs.
I changed my user name in eclipse.ini file.

```
-Duser.name=biadmin
```

I see no changes while submitting my job eventually causing my job to fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried for Hadoop to execute MapReduce jobs as different user.

you may try something similar to this...

```
UserGroupInformation ugi = UserGroupInformation.createRemoteUser("root");

ugi.doAs(new PrivilegedExceptionAction<Void>() { 
//implement run() method here - generally we submit the job in this block   

public Void run(){   
//submit the job in this block 
} 
});
```